# How to get checkboxes values in a form?

Tags: forms, 8

This is my code :

```
$form['how_many'] = [
  '#type' => 'checkboxes',
  '#required' => true,
  '#options' => [
     '1' => t('one'),
     '2' => t('two'),
     '3' => t('three')
  ],
  '#title' => t('How many')
];
```

I want to get the checkbox values.

When I do `$form_state->getValue('how_many');`, I get an array with filed value as well as non-filled as 0.

If i do `$form_state->getValue('how_many[1]');`, I get nothing and if I do `$form_state->getCheckedCheckboxes('how many')`, the page shows nothing.

Comment: What happens if you perform $form_state->getValue(['how_many','#options'])?

Comment: Are you sure you are not looking for radios, and not the multiple return values of checkboxes?

Comment: facing same issue.

Answer (score 3):

May be you can try this:

```
$result = $form_state->getValue('how_many');
$value = array_filter($result);

//print to check the value 

print_r($value);
```

Comment: this will filter out unchecked values, op, wants to know why it is returning 0, even though it is checked?

Comment: Please refer examples module for better understanding , or please elaborate your question

Comment: Make sure Allowed number of values is set to UNLIMITED for a checkbox field.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when using `$form_state->getValue()` you can end up with the first checkbox as checked even if it isn't checked, `getUserInput()` is more accurate.

What you can do instead is this:

```
$selection = $form_state->getUserInput()['how_many'] ?? [];
foreach ($selection as $id => $box) {
  $checked = isset($box);
  // Do something here...
}
```

When something is checked, you'll get a value of 0, otherwise it'll be empty.